# assign integer value given boolean expression on C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

i'm trying to understand a piece of algorithm taken from a c++ code  , here's the C++ code

`inline void DBGame::make_chain( Edge* &newedge, Edge *edges[], Node *node ){
      newedge->length = edges[0]->length + edges[1]->length;`

`for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)`
      `{`

`edges[j]->parent = newedge;
      edges[j]->remove();`

```
  // replace the old edge with the new edge at the other end
  // -------------------------------------------------------
  int k = (edges[j]->node[0] == node);
  newedge->node[j] = edges[j]->node[k];
  newedge->pself[j] = edges[j]->pself[k];
  *newedge->pself[j] = newedge;
  }
```

}

fyi, node is an object and not an integer.
I don't understand how to assign an integer value to `int k`  by giving an true-false expression.

Answer (score 2):

There's an implicit cast of bool to 0 or 1. It doesn't greatly add to readability or efficiency, and is at least partly a result of C not having a bool type.

This line:

```
int k = (edges[j]->node[0] == node);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int k = edges[j]->node[0] == node ? 1 : 0;
```

And juut to add to this, as the original questioner seems to have decided to use the comments to extend the question a lot, there are also implicit casts from numeric types and pointers to bool.

So

```
if (node)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (node != 0)
```

which is another shortcut I'm not exactly enamoured of.

Comment: ok, got it , thanks
sorry, I have another question , here's the code
 
`if (node->edge[j] && node->edge[j] != pedge)`
or
`Node *node = edge->node[0];

   if (node == edge->node[1])
      {
      if (node)
         {
         node->degree = 2;`

do you mind explain the mean of 'if (node->edge[j] ` or ' if (node)` , how' the rule an mean of assigning an object to an if statement , instead of assign a true-false expression

Comment: sorry? I need some english in that statement to make sense of it

Comment: what I mean is usually we give a true-false expression to an if statement,like if (A==B). but in the code the  there's no boolean expression, it use  an object as an expression , `if(node)` , node is an object not an expression

Comment: how does assigning  an object to an if statement works in c++?

Comment: Node is a pointer, so `if (node)` will evaluate to false if the pointer is null

Answer (score 0):

false is 0, true is everything except 0

Answer (score 0):

The type of the result of `edges[j]->node[0] == node` is `bool`. 
It can be implicitly converted to `int`, `false` becoming 0 and `true` becoming a non-zero value, usually, 1.

Comment: ok, thanks.. got it .sorry .. I have another question, how does assigning an object to an if statement works in c++? example `if(node[a][b]) {...}`  what I know, usually Iwe assign a true-false expression to an if instead of an object

Comment: Here it works other way around. An expression is implicitly converted to `bool`, equivalent to `if(node[a][b] != 0)`

Comment: nice , thanks, your explaination really healpful for a newbie like me :)

Comment: @Andrey I think there is a minimum reputation score required to up-vote, unfortunately.

Comment: @juanchopanza: does that apply to answers for his own question?